# Stack sorting between 3 stacks of Integers

Tags: java, sorting, stack

What am I missing to complete the problem?

the homework problem says:

Suppose you have 3 stacks of integers, s1 (which has values in it), s2 (which is empty) and s3 (also empty). Write code to sort the entries in s1, using the algorithm given here (the sorted values will be in s2 at the end):
At any point in time, s2 will hold entries in sorted order, with the smallest value at the top. Move the top entry of s1 to s2. Remove and consider the top entry t of s1. Remove entries of stack s2 and put them onto stack s3 until you reach the correct place to put t. Then put t onto s2. Next move all the entries from s3 to s2.

my code so far:

```
public class practice2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Stack<Integer> s1 = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> s2 = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> s3 = new Stack<Integer>();

    s1.push(1);
    s1.push(61);
    s1.push(21);
    s1.push(31);
    s1.push(51);
    s1.push(111);

    s2.push(s1.pop());

    while(!s1.isEmpty())
    {
        if(s1.peek() < s2.peek())
        {
            s2.push(s1.pop());
        }
        else
        {
            s3.push(s1.pop());
        }
    }

    if(s2.peek() < s3.peek())
    {
        while(!s2.isEmpty())
        {
            s1.push(s2.pop());
        }
    }

    while(!s1.isEmpty())
    {
        if(s1.peek() > s3.peek())
        {
            s2.push(s1.pop());
        }
        else
        s2.push(s3.pop());
    }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not follow the algorithm you have given. The algorithm you are meant to implement is

1. Remove and consider the top entry **t** of **s1**.
2. Remove entries of stack **s2** and put them onto stack **s3** until you reach the correct place to put **t**.
3. Then put **t** onto **s2**.
4. Next move all the entries from **s3** to **s2**.

---

So write pseudocode which does this:

1. Get/peek at **s1** - **t**
2. While **t** greater then top of **s2**, push top of **s2** onto **s3**
3. Push **t** on **s2**
4. while **s3** is not empty push top of **s3** onto **s2**
5. repeat for all of **s1**

---

Currently your code does the following:

1. While **s1** is not empty: If top of **s1** less than top of **s2**

   - then push top onto **s2**
   - else push onto **s3**
2. If the top of **s2** is less than the top of **s3**

   - Push all of **s2** onto **s1**
3. While **s1** is not empty: If top of **s1** is larger then the top of **s3**

   - then Push top of **s1** onto **s2**
   - else push top of **s3** onto **s2**

Hope this helps.